# Why one Django database query is working when similar one is not

Tags: django, database, forms

I reused similar code twice but on one occasion it doesn't add anything to database, can anyone tell me why? Lack of form validation is the problem?

I'm trying to increase some user model fields by certain integer every time form is sent to server. One of them working, one doesn't.

Code below increase amount_comments by one every time:

```py
def add_comment(request, pk):
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.ticket = ticket
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
            user.amount_comments += 1
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Comment added!'))
            return redirect('show_single', pk=pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'add_comment.html', {'form': form})
```

...and this one doesn't increase contributions for some reason:

```py
def show(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
        user.contributions += 5
        user.save()
        return redirect('checkout', pk=pk)
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=pk)
    comment_list = Comment.objects.select_related().filter(
                   ticket_id=pk).order_by('-date')
    paginator = Paginator(comment_list, 4)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    comments = paginator.get_page(page)
    key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    return render(request, 'single_ticket.html', {'ticket': ticket, 'comments':
                  comments, 'key': key})
```

I don't get any errors just checking admin panel and user doesn't get his contributions field changed by 5 when amount_comments goes up every time.

CustomUser extends AbstractUser with two fields added:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    contributions = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    amount_comments = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

On second occasion checkout.js is the library used for the form:

```html
<form action="{% url 'checkout' ticket.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
    class="stripe-button"
    data-key={{ key }}
    data-description="Payment"
    data-amount="500"
    data-currency="gbp"
    data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('ticket/', include('ticket.urls')),
    path('checkout/', include('checkout.urls')),
    path('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('sign_up', views.sign_up, name='sign_up'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
    path('all_tickets/', views.all_tickets, name='all_tickets')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

checkout app urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
]
```

tickets app urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('delete/<ticket_id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('show/<int:pk>', views.show, name='show_single'),
    path('show/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
    path('add', views.add_ticket, name='add_ticket'),
]
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing the CustomUser model and how you are calling the view.

Comment: Show your urls.py

Comment: I found walk-around it added code to checkout views.py:  

`code`def checkout(request, pk):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
    user.contributions += 5
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', {'ticket': ticket})

Answer (score 1):

You're posting to `{% url 'checkout' ticket.id %}` which is linked here `path('<int:pk>', views.checkout, name='checkout')` to `views.checkout`, not `show`. So this code (`show`) was never executed for given form. Change URL pattern name in this template tag to the correct one:

`{% url 'show_single' ticket.id %}`